# Reference request with examples, finite difference method for $1D$ heat equation ,with mixed boundary conditions.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am looking for book or online material on numerical (finite difference method) solution of $1D$ heat equation, given initial distribution of temperature, with mixed boundary conditions: Dirichlet condition at one end of the rod and Robin condition at the other end of the rod.

Using Crank-Nicholson Method, Explicit method and Implicit method.

It is better if book contains example of solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing" contains a straightforward introduction to this sort of numerical exercise. I don't suppose it specifically talks about the Robin condition but probably it's not too hard to work out the details yourself.
http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=1024#